# Integrate material ui into angular bazel project

Tags: angular, bazel

I have a question how to import material ui using bazel?

I have global `styles.scss` file, this file has import like `@use '@angular/material' as mat;` , what I need to do to resolve dependency. I found [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_sass#sass_library) an example how to do this

```
npm_sass_library(
  name = "angular_material_sass_deps",
  deps = ["@npm//@angular/material"],
)

sass_binary(
  name = "my_theme"
  src = "my_theme.scss",
  deps = [":angular_material_sass_deps"],
)
```

But it doesn’t work. With error:

```
INFO: Invocation ID: fbe608d9-f411-44de-8e7d-3a0326734865
INFO: Analyzed target //browserclient/src:prodapp (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From SassCompiler browserclient/src/styles.css:
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │ @use '@angular/material' as mat;
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  browserclient/src/styles.scss 2:1  root stylesheet
ERROR: /Users/yhierts/Desktop/charitize/browserclient/src/BUILD.bazel:22:12: output 'browserclient/src/styles.css' was not created
ERROR: /Users/yhierts/Desktop/charitize/browserclient/src/BUILD.bazel:22:12: output 'browserclient/src/styles.css.map' was not created
ERROR: /Users/yhierts/Desktop/charitize/browserclient/src/BUILD.bazel:22:12: SassCompiler browserclient/src/styles.css failed: not all outputs were created or valid
Target //browserclient/src:prodapp failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.396s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 2 processes: 1 remote cache hit, 1 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Note the **`include_paths`** that make the resolution work so that you can resolve packages from the `@npm` workspace, and its `node_modules`.

The `npm_sass_library` rule is built exactly for this use-case. More details here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_sass/commit/57089530cbf87c68bb2f6b803b3d48022f210e35

```
npm_sass_library(
  name = "angular_material_sass_deps",
  deps = ["@npm//@angular/material"],
)

sass_binary(
  name = "my_theme"
  src = "my_theme.scss",
  include_paths = [
    "external/npm/node_modules",
  ],
  deps = [":angular_material_sass_deps"],
)
```

*my_theme.scss*

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

// do something with the theming API
```

Comment: Thank you Paul! Also in addition if npm has other then default name `@npm` eg: `@bc_npm`, you also have to change "external/bc_npm/node_modules" path.

Comment: What about IDE? IDE webstorm can't see this path, how did you solve this issue?

Comment: I think you would need to mark the node modules directoy as resource root in Webstorm. Although that is really a configuration thing of the IDE then. Webstorm wouldn't detect it automatically if I used e.g. Webpack with some custom Sass settings